# Getting error while running RTSP live streaming in ICS

Tags: android, media-player, inputstream, rtsp

I trying to play RTSP live streaming through both `VideoView` and `MediaPlayer`... I am able to get the stream both AAC audio and H264 Video. But after 15-20 minutes, RTSP stack is getting fulled and it's crashing my application and tablet also... So is there any solution to increase the size of RTSP stack in Android source code? (I have whole AOSP ICS code). Any kind of help appreciable.

@Ganesh Please find the Application Source Code below.

```
package com.example.testvideo;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        VideoView videoDisplay = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
        videoDisplay.setVideoPath("rtsp://192.168.2.160:554/live/av0?user=admin&passwd=admin");
        videoDisplay.start();

        /*VideoView videoDisplay2 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview2);
        videoDisplay2.setVideoPath("rtsp://192.168.2.160:554/live/av1?user=admin&passwd=admin");
        //videoDisplay2.start();
*/      

        try {
              File filename = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Sample_log_file.txt");
              filename.createNewFile();
              String cmd = "logcat -d -f "+filename.getAbsolutePath();
              Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
           } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            } 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on `RTSP` stack getting filled? If your question was that data from `RTSP` is not being read, then most probably one of your codecs is not draining data. Please attach any logs from your crash which can analyzed further.

Comment: @Ganesh Thanks for your reply.Actually RTSP streaming is playing for 15 min. We are able to get RTSP data also but after 15 min all the services(like Surfaceflinger,AudioFliger) getting died and its crashing the app.Please find the below link for logcat file.You can check it.If any changes or suggestion from your side appreciable.

Comment: @Prashant.. couldn't find the link to `logcat` file

Comment: @Ganesh Sorry I forgot to attach. Please find the logcat file in below link. http://pastebin.com/2HjP6QM0

Answer (score 0):

From the logs attached [here](http://pastebin.com/2HjP6QM0), I observe the following prints:

```
Line no. 4060: F/libc    ( 1203): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1)
```

which means your code has crashed. Further down in the log,

```
Line no. 4084: I/DEBUG   (   83): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
```

From the stack trace of your crash log,

```
I/DEBUG   (   83):          #00  pc 0000db2c  /system/lib/libc.so (memcpy)
I/DEBUG   (   83):          #01  pc 000710ec  /system/lib/libCedarX.so (rtsp_demux_read)
I/DEBUG   (   83):          #02  pc 000636dc  /system/lib/libCedarX.so
I/DEBUG   (   83):          #03  pc 00012be4  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry)
I/DEBUG   (   83):          #04  pc 00012738  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create)
```

**Conclusion:**

From these points, I conclude that in `rtsp_demux_read` function, there is a `memcpy` call. When your program has crashed, you have passed a `NULL` pointer as mostly the *destination* to the `memcpy` function. You would require to debug your code further on why this could happen.

Comment: Thanks for your support.I am not getting what you mean to say Is this the problem from android framework side or my application code side.Can you please elaborate the things.

Comment: @Prashant From the logs and functions, I feel the issue is in `rtsp_demux` which is part of `libCedarX.so`. I don't think this is part of standard `AOSP` distribution and hence, I feel the issue could probably be in your customizations

Comment: Hi I tried to find out solution but i did not get. Still I am getting the same error.I wanted the help from you if you know.Please check out the latest errors and application Source code in the above question where I edited. Please check and give any kind of suggestion.Find the link of Error logs http://pastebin.com/uw0zWMGJ

Comment: @GaneshWhatever you told these things i tried to search on net but i did not get any solution on this.If you know any thing on this issue just let me know.Please I am just stuck here.For more explanation i edit the my application Source Code also in the above question.Please check and give me any suggestion on this.As well as find Error Log link using same code on ICS-4.0.3. [http://pastebin.com/uw0zWMGJ]

Comment: @Prashant From your logs, I am unable to get any pointers. From my search, I feel `libCedarX` is not a standard android module and is your specific customization. I feel you should request for help from some of your mentors. In case I find any pointers, I will share the same.

Comment: @GaneshThanks for your all support.Did you saw my application source code.